# Returning the result of divided number with a Scale in a Select Statement

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying to run this query, but it seems like it's not formatting the numbers properly after doing a mathematical calculation.  The scale should be at 2, but it won't display as it should.

```
SELECT 30 / 60 as Diff FROM Table
```

This returns as `0`

```
SELECT Convert( Numeric(8,2), 30 / 60 ) as Diff FROM Table
```

This returns as `0.00`

How do I get this to return `0.50` as needed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following and there are few ways to achieve it. Using a variable, or just performing `CAST`, `CONVERT` on the fields itself.

```
 SELECT (CAST(30 AS DECIMAL(8,2)) / CAST(60 AS DECIMAL(8,2))) as Diff FROM Table

 SELECT (CAST(30/60) AS DECIMAL(8,2)) as Diff FROM Table

 SELECT (30/60.0) as Diff FROM Table;

 SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(8,2), 30/60.0) as Diff FROM Table
```

Please take a look at this [MSDN article for further reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx):

Answer (score 1):

Convert to numeric before doing the division or divide real numbers instead of integers.  When doing integer arithmetic any decimal fraction is dropped.  Converting after the fraction has been dropped doesn't do you any good.

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(8,2),30.0/60.0) AS DIFF FROM TABLE
```

or if selecting columns instead of using numbers

```
SELECT CONVERT(NUMERIC(8,2),columnA)/CONVERT(NUMERIC(8,2),columnB) AS DIFF FROM TABLE
```

(converting both just to be sure the division is done according to the rules we want)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can you give an example please?

Comment: @tvanfosson Hi thanks for noticing the earlier typo :) I was putting a back and forth conversion, I reckon.